# Making workable JSON file with Angularjs1

Tags: angularjs, json

I have file that looks like this when I navigate to my local host server

URL:

```
http://localhost:9000/read/lol.json
```

And output looks like this:

```
"{\n  \"firstName\" : \"Vladimir\"\n}\n"
```

Now, what I want is to read this file, so I made service in angular:

```
.service('messageService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    this.getMessage = function(firstName) {
        var gmList = $resource("read/lol.json");

        return gmList.get({
            firstName : firstName
        });
    };
}]);
```

and my controller.js

```
.controller('messageService', function(messageService){


  this.firstName = messageService.firstName;

  this.messageResult = messageService.getMessage(this.firstName);
});
```

Finally, my html file

```
<div data-ng-controller="messageService as mService">
  <p>This is new controller: </p>
  <div >
    <ul data-ng-repeat="w in mService.messageResult">
      <li>{{w.firstName}}</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

EDIT! This is how I got my output when i go to /read/lol.json
Its in java, to be precise, Play Framework.

```
public Result getFileContent(String filename) throws IOException {

    String publicFolder = _appEnvironment.rootPath().getAbsolutePath().concat(folder);

    String result = "";

    FileReader in = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    File dataFile = new File(publicFolder + filename);

    try {
        in = new FileReader(dataFile);

        br = new BufferedReader(in);

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result.concat(line).concat("\n");
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    return ok(Json.toJson(result));
}
```

Thats it. I feel something needs to be done to ignore those \n and .
When I load my page, I get empty list (dots and nothing in that list, just dots).
However, when I look in console, my lol.json file has status 200. I GET that file but cant get anything from it (object).

What is the problem?

Comment: How did you create that json file? It does not look as valid. Should be like this: {"firstName": "Vladimir"}

Comment: To validate your JSON, use: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I edited my post below, see how it is written in backend.

Comment: By the way, the JSON is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of JSON.parse. The code is below:

```js
var data=JSON.parse("{\n  \"firstName\" : \"Vladimir\"\n}\n"
);
console.log(data.firstName);
```

It would convert the string to javascript object format. And to get value of firstname, just log data.firstname.

Comment: Sure, that works. And when go data.firstName, output is "Vladimir". How to get rid of ""?

Comment: Well, let me explain. When you just do console.log(data) you would just receive log as 'Object' so we usually do JSON.stringify(data) to get the actual json as a string . That's why you were able to see quotes. Check my updated code eliminating JSON.stringify, it serves what you needed,